# Exit value with piped commands in bash

Tags: bash

Whenever the output of a command is piped to another in bash, which command will the exit value (the `$?` variable) be returned from? The command that the output was piped from, or the command that the output was piped to?

Say, for example, in the command:

```
git diff | vim -
```

Would the `$?` variable come from the `git diff` command, or the `vim -` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last command in the pipe.

```
$ false | echo -n
$ echo $?
0

$ true | echo -n
$ echo $?
0

$ true | echo -n | false
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 6):

`man bash` says:

```
   ?      Expands to the exit status of the most recently  executed  fore‐
          ground pipeline.
```

And:

```
   The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command,
   unless the pipefail option is enabled.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$?` keeps the status of the last executed command in a pipeline, but if you want to check the status of a command inside the pipeline use the `PIPESTATUS` variable, which is

> An array variable (see Arrays) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

In your example the return status of `git diff` can be read from `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.