# BASH pipe exit code

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, grep, exit-code

I was writing a simple script that checks for a certain keyword in the output of a command. To see if it works, I was checking the command from the bash command line.

```bash
$ ls | grep -q foo
$ echo $?
```

It displayed 1 or 0, depending on the command output and the grep parameter as expected.

I got tired of retyping the command, so I added `| echo $?` at the end of the command line.

```bash
$ ls | grep -q foo | echo $?
```

Then, regardless of the command output, it always returns 0, even if the first part should return 1.

I guess this is normal behavior but I'd like to know why bash works this way.

Comment: similar: http://superuser.com/questions/280879/exit-value-with-piped-commands-in-bash?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the pipe takes the stdout and pipes it to the next command, what you want instead is the semicolon.

`ls | grep -q foo; echo $?`

This finished the `ls` and `grep` commands and then executes the `echo` command.

Comment: The solution may be correct, but the argumentation is not convincing.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $ ls | grep -q foo | echo $?
> ```
>
> Then, regardless of the command output, it always returns 0, even if the first part should return 1.

More precisely, the `echo $?` in this pipeline will print the exit code of the previous command executed before the pipeline.
In this example it will output 7:

```
( exit 7 )
ls / | grep . | echo $?
```

After you type `ls | grep -q foo | echo $?` and press enter on the command line, the following will happen (among other things):

- The shell parses and interprets the command line.

  - It substitutes the variable `$?` with the exit code of the previous command that was executed before you pressed enter.
  - For example if the previous command exited with 7, then the shell concludes the command to execute is `ls | grep -q foo | echo 7`
- It executes the command.

In other words, the moment you press enter to execute the pipeline `ls | grep -q foo | echo $?`, the shell parses and interprets the line it received, and evaluates the variable `$?` before even beginning to execute the commands in the pipeline.

---

On a related note, you can use the exit code directly in conditional statements, for example:

```
if ls | grep -q foo; then echo success, there is foo; fi
```

Or, if you want to execute something on success,
you could chain the next command using `&&`:

```
ls | grep -q foo && echo success
```

Comment: The argumentation is not convincing: For `echo $?`, how can `$?` be set to the result of `echo $?` before the command had exited?

Comment: @U.Windl you're right, that was weak. I rewrote that part, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: There is still an issue: The commands making up the pipeline are started in parallel, so `$?` is expanded before any command making up the pipeline is actually run; thus it will be the result of the previous command. However the question was about using `echo $?` *after* having run the pipeline.

Comment: @U.Windl Strictly speaking the OP doesn't ask any questions explicitly. It makes a statement that is inaccurate, and there is an implied question "why does it behave this way". I rephrased my answer to make the original statement more accurate, and clarified the explanation of the behavior.